# generateStaticParams unexpected returns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to generate slugs using generateStaticParams in Next but it somehow "chooses" diferent data to return that I want it to.

function generateSlugs(params) return array of slug objects each containing slug and id.

My problem is that generateStaticParams uses id as slug in returned values instead of slug. What could be wrong?

```
import Gallery from "@/app/components/Gallery";
import ProductDescription from "@/app/components/ProductDescription";
import Navbar from "@/app/layout/Navbar";
import ProductSection from "@/app/layout/ProductSection";
import Products from "@/app/layout/Products";
import { Metadata, ResolvingMetadata } from "next";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import { Slug } from "@/app/types/types";
import { ProductPage } from "@/app/types/types";
import { getData } from "@/app/utils/getData";
import generateSlugs from "@/app/utils/generateSlugs";

export const preferredRegion = ["fra1"];
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const params = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/auctions`).then(
    (res) => res.json()
  );

  const slugs = generateSlugs(params);

  return slugs.map((slug: Slug) => ({
    slug: slug.slug,
  }));
}

export async function generateMetadata(
  { params }: { params: Slug },
  parent: ResolvingMetadata
): Promise<Metadata> {
  console.log(params);

  const product = await getData(params);
  const url = "https://noanzo.pl";
  return {
    title: `${product[0]?.title} - noanzo.pl`,
    description: product[0]?.description,
    robots: "index, follow",
    alternates: {
      canonical: `${url}/produkt/${params.slug}`,
    },
    openGraph: {
      title: `${product[0]?.title} - noanzo.pl`,
      description: product[0]?.description,
      locale: "pl",
      images: [
        {
          url: (() => {
            const link = product[0]?.image.filter(
              (item: any) => item.thumbnail === true
            );
            if (!product[0]) {
              notFound();
            }
            if (link[0]?.url) {
              return link[0].url;
            } else {
              return product[0].image[0].url;
            }
          })(),
          alt: product[0]?.title,
        },
      ],
    },
  };
}

export default async function Page({ params }: { params: Slug }) {
  const data = await getData(params);
  if (!data || data[0] === null) {
    notFound();
  }
  const product: ProductPage = {
    title: data[0].title,
    description: data[0].description,
    price: data[0].price,
    image: data[0].image,
    imageLarge: data[0].imageLarge,
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <Navbar />
      <div className='container mx-auto sm:w-4/5 lg:w-11/12 xl:sm:w-4/5 p-2'>
        <ProductSection>
          <Gallery product={product} />
          <ProductDescription product={product} />
        </ProductSection>
      </div>
      <Products />
    </main>
  );
}
```

When i try something like this:

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const params = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/auctions`).then(
    (res) => res.json()
  );

  return params.map((slug: Slug) => ({
    slug: slug.slug,
  }));
}
```

Above code works and returns id's of each item returned from api as slug. How does it "decide" to choose "id" instead of eg. "title" which is also in my data:

Here's link to my data: [api link](https://admin.noanzo.pl/api/auctions)

generateSlugs definition:

```
const generateSlugs = (params: Array<any>) => {
  const slugs = params.map((item: any) => {
    let slug = item.title.replace(/\s+/g, "-");
    if (!slug.endsWith("-")) {
      slug = slug + "-";
    }
    slug = slug + item.id.substring(0, 8);
    return { slug: slug.toLowerCase(), id: item.id };
  });
  return slugs;
};

export default generateSlugs;
```

Comment: Can you show us how `generateSlugs(params)` is defined?

Comment: @FiddlingAway just added its definition.

Comment: I can't find any faults in `generateSlugs(params)` nor in `generateStaticParams()`, as can be seen in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/reoy7b38/ . Looking at the rest of your code, I see that you're logging `params` to the console. What does that console output look like?

Comment: Looks like this:
`{ slug: '9bc56d96-01e4-4bf9-b4a4-de7c31e6d544' }`

Seems ok but I can't figure out why is it using "id" instead of "slug".